# Flutter FirebaseDatabase run transaction crash

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, transactions

i'm trying run a transaction in the firebase database using Flutter and i am getting an error, can someone help me to solve this?

Code:

```
ref.runTransaction((MutableData transaction) async {
      transaction.value = (transaction.value ?? 0) + 1;
      return transaction;
    });
```

Error:

```
E/RepoOperation(16416): Caught Throwable.
E/RepoOperation(16416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: FirebaseDatabaseWorker
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:605)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.dispatchPlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:515)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.send(DartMessenger.java:76)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.send(DartExecutor.java:166)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.send(FlutterNativeView.java:155)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:98)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabasePlugin$1.doTransaction(FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:345)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.startTransaction(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:831)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$4.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:511)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/RepoOperation(16416):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error while using flutter `dev channel`.
Going to `stable channel` fixed it for me. To check which channel you are do `flutter channel`

To switch to stable channel do:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: You right, the version stable is working, it get crashed in some version after the version 1.5.8 i guess. Thank you.

Comment: i added as issue for Flutter , follow it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33562

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks!! Is the flutter upgrade command required? It resulted in some breaking changes in my pubspec.yaml file that I had to go in and fix.

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed by [flutter/flutter#33562](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33562) & [FirebaseExtended/flutterfire#1072](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1072) & [flutter/plugins#1812](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1812)